# Spring Integration - Can a message store be persistent to a queue?

Tags: spring-integration

**Question:** How to roll back messages in a Message Store back to a queue if a system failure occurs?

**Scenerio:** 
IBM MQ Queue --> JMS Message Drive Channel Adapter--> Aggregator.

During a system failure that results in the a JVM shut down. Instead of using the default volatile message store could I specify a MQ queue to act as the persistent message store? That way if a system failure occurs the messages in the message store could be rolled back a MQ persistent queue for fail over handling.

EDIT: Last sentence for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by...

> could be rolled back to the originating queue

...if you mean automatically then, no.

There's a JDBC message store implementation (but you'd need XA transactions).

You could probably create a custom message store backed by JMS, but it's an unusual use of a queue - I suppose you'd have to use a message selector based on the `groupId` but you'd probably have to keep a mirror in memory (and initialize it during system initialization, while leaving the messages in the queue).

Comment: To clairfy, it doesn't have to go the originating queue. So long as on failure of a system that I could persist the messages into a queue that would be fine. The goal is to implement fail over scenario for the messages that were left over in the Message Store. Is it possible to roll those back into a queue?

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you mean. If you write a queue-backed message store, the messages are already in a queue so there's nothing to roll back. But, as I also said, using a queue as a store is a bit unusual.

Comment: Ok, that's what I am looking to do. To have a queue-backed message store. So for that I would have to do a custom-message store. Can you point me to any examples showing custom message store?  You say it be a bit unusual, may I ask why ? A queue provides persistence, if a failure occurs another process can pick up where it left off without the need to create any tables in the database.

Comment: The problem is that the aggregator needs access to the complete group (so the release strategy can determine whether it's time to release). So you would need to keep a parallel memory copy of the group. The real issue is how to reinstate that memory copy after a restart; you'd have to somehow browse the queue and/or read the messages and send them back to the queue. Tricky stuff.

Comment: Ok so this is the technical response I was looking for. So for persistence this is why it's best for message store to use the jdbc persistent store.